# Google Data Studio - Custom Aggregation formula

Tags: looker-studio

I am building a report in Google Data Studio, and I run into a problem with the aggregation for a couple of metrics.

As an example, I have the following table:

```
name. |. M1. |. M2. |. M3
  A.     23     45     1,9
  B.     45     6      0,1
  C.     23     45     1,9
  D.     12     34     2,8
  E.     4      2      0,5
```

Where

```
M3 = M2/M1
```

Now, when I display this in a table in GDS, the totals for M1 and M2 are the sum of the values, and that is ok, but I can only choose between fixed aggregation operations, and the total for M3 should be:

```
Total M3 = sum(M2)/sum(M1)
```

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom field:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en

Comment: Yes I acctually figured it out just after posting the question... My calculated field used the formula M2/M1, instead of sum(M2)/sum(M1).